“paradox of the Cartesian method.”
Is this True or not?
For simple problems or ones we’ve already solved, focusing directly on the goal works well. But for more complex problems, this approach doesn’t work effectively. Why? Because when we focus only on the goal, we often skip learning the tools and knowledge needed to solve the problem. Sometimes, getting these tools is either not possible or takes too much time.
Without the right tools and knowledge, we end up guessing, trying random ideas, or using incomplete methods.
On the other hand, if we try to solve the problem step by step, making sure we have all the tools and knowledge, we lose focus on the goal. This is because we spend time learning what’s needed instead of working directly on the problem. Sometimes, we even have to learn the basics before solving the problem. This creates what we can call the “paradox of the Cartesian method.”
This may seem strange. If being "Cartesian" means being clear, logical, and systematic, and if focusing on the goal means working directly on the problem, this paradox shows we can’t do both at the same time for complex problems. These two approaches clash with each other.
If we want to be clear and systematic, we must accept some delay in reaching the goal. If we want to focus directly on the goal, we must accept using random, quick, and sometimes illogical methods.
The best solution might be finding a balance between these two ways. Or, it could be about knowing which phase we are in while solving the problem and choosing the right approach for that phase.
Are we in Phase A, focusing on the goal, testing quick and random ideas, even if they’re not systematic? Or are we in Phase B, fixing gaps in our knowledge and using more organized and structured methods?

"we even have to learn the basics before solving the problem" - that seems pretty straightforwardly true in all cases, doesn't it? I wouldn't expect anyone to be able to identify a vector field as Killing or non-Killing before learning at least a little bit of differential geometry.

Now that you know the risk to loose sight of both requirements - to remember the goal and to learn the tools - you can avoid both problems. There is no need to construct a "paradox of the Cartesian method".
Anyhow, one may find the solution to a problem on many quite different ways, not necessarily by working in a clear step-by-step method.
But when proving or checking at "the next morning" the result from the previous day, one has to work with clear and distinct concepts - according to Descartes' recommendation.
